# searching a hash in a string with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to get this bold part from this string:

```
some other code src='/pages/captcha?t=c&s=**51afb384edfc&h=513cc6f5349b**' `</td><td><input type=text name=captchaenter id=captchaenter size=3`
```

This is my regex that is not working:

```
Regex("src=\\'/pages/captcha\\?t=c&s=([\\d\\w&=]+)\\'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

In tool for regex testing it's working.

How can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Helpful tool for testing/creating regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string-based regex is different from the regex you tested in the tool.  In your regex, you have [\d\w\W]+ which matches any character and is aggressive (i.e. no ? after + to make it non-aggressive).  So it may match a very long string, which may be all the way up to the *last* end quote.

In your tool you have [\d\w&=] which only matches digits, letters, & and =, so obviously it will stop when hitting the end quote.

Answer (score 0):

The regex's aren't the same. The one in code has a character class (`[\\d\\w\\W]+`) that is different from the one in the tool (`[\\d\\w&=]+]`)

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine with this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "src='/pages/captcha?t=c&s=51afb384edfc&h=513cc6f5349b' </td><td><input type=text name=captchaenter id=captchaenter size=3";
            Regex rgx = new Regex("src=\\'/pages/captcha\\?t=c&s=([\\d\\w\\W]+)\\'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match m = rgx.Match(s);
            Console.Write(m.Groups[1]);

        }
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
    51afb384edfc&h=513cc6f5349b
```

Answer (score -1):

I despise regular expressions. I would do it similar to (but safer than) this:

```
    private static string GetStuff(string source)
    {
        var start = source.IndexOf("s=") + 2;
        var end = source.IndexOf('\'', start + 3);
        return source.Substring(start, end - start);
    }
```

Comment: Chuckle. Ok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951240/regex-vs-string-manipulation-functions-what-is-better